# How do I make a test runner that can execute tagged MSpec tests?

Tags: c#, mspec, test-runner

I have a suite of mspec test cases that has the `[Tags]` attribute defined for each. I now have to create a test runner in .Net/C# that takes the tags attribute values(an array of strings) as input and runs the corresponding tests. I would like to know how I can go about doing this - just some pointers to get started.

*I don't have any control over the test scripts, so cannot modify them. Also, I cannot use any third party test runners.*

Comment: Does Alexander's answer work for you? The MSpec library package comes with it's own 1st party runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the bundled runner (`mspec.exe`) and pass the `--include` or `--exclude` parameter with a list of tags to include in the run or exclude from the run.

Comment: Any examples on how to use `--include` or `--exclude'

Comment: `mspec.exe --include foo,bar specs.dll` and don't forget to `[Tags("foo")]` on any context.